# HTML CSS Появление слайдера снизу

Tags: html, css, слайдер

Друзья! Столкнулся с проблемой при вёрстке страницы. Дело в том, что снизу появляется слайдер, которого там быть не должно.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500|Nunito+Sans&display=swap');
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.header-container {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100px;
 background: #fff;
}
.logo {
 float: left;
 padding-top: 38px;
 padding-left: 7vw;
}
.nav {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 45px;
 padding-right: 7vw;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.menu-list-element {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 2vw;
 color: #191919;
}
.menu-list-element.active, .menu-list-element:hover {
 color: #10c9c3;
 cursor: pointer;
}




.container {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -ms-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
 -moz-flex-direction: column;
 -ms-flex-direction: column;
 -o-flex-direction: column;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -ms-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
 -moz-flex-direction: column;
 -ms-flex-direction: column;
 -o-flex-direction: column;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 38vw;
}
h1 {
 display: -webkit-inline-flex;
 display: -moz-inline-flex;
 display: -ms-inline-flex;
 display: -o-inline-flex;
 display: inline-flex;
 font-size: 38px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-weight: 600;
 text-align: center;
 color: #171717;
}
.under-text {
 display: -webkit-inline-flex;
 display: -moz-inline-flex;
 display: -ms-inline-flex;
 display: -o-inline-flex;
 display: inline-flex;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 23px;
 color: #787878;
}


.images {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 97px;
 float: left;
}
.light-block, .dark-block {
 width: 25%;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
}
.light-block {
 background-color: #ddd;
}
.dark-block {
 background-color: #838383;
}
.cyan-block {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 -ms-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #21bfb9;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
 z-index: 1;
}
.cyan-block:hover {
 opacity: 70%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.cyan-block img {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 z-index: 2;
 opacity: 100%;
}



.footer-container {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 284px;
 padding: auto 0;
 background-color: #141414;
}
.copyright {
 float: left;
}
[![Слайдер][1]][1]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Amelia Woods</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body class="load">
 <header>
  <div class="header-container">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" />
   </div>
   <div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu-list">
     <li class="menu-list-element active">home</li>
     <li class="menu-list-element">about</li>
     <li class="menu-list-element">contact</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="text">
    <h1>UI/UX & Graphic Designer</h1>
    <span class="under-text">I am a Graphic & Web Designer based in New York, specializing in User Interface Design and Development</span>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
    <div class="light-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="light-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="light-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="light-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="light-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="light-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-block">
     <div class="cyan-block">
      <img src="eye.png" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
  <div class="footer-container">
   <div class="copyright">
    <span class="header">Piroll Design, Inc.</span>
   </div>
   <div class="contacts">1</div>
   <div class="links">2</div>
   <div class="social">3</div>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду появляется прокрутка? Я не понимаю, что значит: 'появляется слайдер'

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно если добавить в CSS строчку:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Это решит Вашу проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно было у `.header-container` убрать свойство `width`.